# Contar quantas vezes cada caractere aparece em uma string (sem uso de função)

Tags: c, string, loop

Estou com a dúvida em uma questão de exercícios de string que estou fazendo. A questão é esta abaixo:

> Escreva um programa que leia uma string e imprima quantas vezes cada
>   caractere
>
> aparece nessa string
>
> 1ª string:
>
> ```
> TTAAC
> ```
>
> Resultado:
>
> ```
> T: 2X
> A: 2X
> C: 1X
> ```

Lembrando que não pode ser feito usando função alguma.

Comment: Você pode usar um vetor inicializado com 0 em todas as 128 casas e então pra cada letra `l` fazer `count[l]++`

Comment: Sem usar função nativa do C, ou sem criar uma função para fazer isso?

Comment: O StackOverFlow não distribui código, somente corrigi ou revisa

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado to utilizando 2 for pra fazer a comparação de um dentro do outro pra e somando pra ver se consegue puxar a soma, parece que está fluindo, do jeito que você mandou ai! Obrigado

Comment: Tenho quase a certeza que essa é duplicada, mas não consegui ainda achar. Já vi essa pergunta algumas vezes por aqui

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Código finalizado!! **EDITADO**

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    char str[30];
    int i, j, count = 0, aux = 0, c = 1;

    puts("Informe a String");
    gets(str);

    while (str[count] != '\0'){
        count++;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){ 
        aux = 1; 
        for(j = i + 1; j < count; j++){ 
            if(str[i] == str[j]){ 
                aux++; 
            } else
                break;
        }   
        if(i == 0) 
          c = 1; 
        else{
          for(j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--){ 
            if(str[i] != str[j])
              c = 1;
            else{ 
              c = 0;
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        if(c == 1)
        printf("\n%c : %d", str[i], cont);
    }


}
```

Comment: Essa resposta não apresenta o resultado correto para `banana`, ou mesmo `ana`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Código corrigido!!

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo de como contar as ocorrências de um mesmo caractere presente em uma string em `C`. (Este exemplo não considera iguais os chars 'A' e 'a').

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int isAlpha(char c) {
  if(c >= 48 && c <= 57) { // [0-9]
    return 1;
  }

  if(c >= 65 && c <= 90) { // [A-Z]
    return 1; 
  }

  if(c >= 97 && c <= 122) { // [a-z]
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    int *map = (int *)calloc(128, sizeof(int));
    int i = 0;

    char *test = "banana";
    char tmp;

    do {
        tmp = test[i++];
        if (isAlpha(tmp)) {
            map[tmp]++;
        }
    } while (tmp != '\0');

    for (i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
        if (map[i] != 0) {
            printf("%c = %d\n", i, map[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```